# Unable to Access @attributes in XML Node

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to access the 'field' element in the 'criteria' node in the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result>
    <product>
        <data>
            <field>spr_tech1</field>
            <value>S7</value>
            <criteria field="xfield_3">
                <criteria_list>Green</criteria_list>
                <criteria_list>Beige</criteria_list>
            </criteria>
        </data>
        <data>
            <field>spr_tech1</field>
            <value>S1</value>
            <criteria field="xfield_3">
                <criteria_list>Red</criteria_list>
                <criteria_list>Blue</criteria_list>
                <criteria_list>Yellow</criteria_list>
            </criteria>
        </data>
        <data>
            <field>spr_tech1</field>
            <value>S7</value>
            <criteria field="xfield_3">
                <criteria_list>Green</criteria_list>
            </criteria>
            <criteria field="tech_rt2">
                <criteria_list>Transistor</criteria_list>
            </criteria>
        </data>
    </product>
</result>
```

The code below results in the following error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object

```
function parseXmlFile($filename)
{
    $xml = file_get_contents($filename);
    $obj = simplexml_load_string($xml, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
    $array = json_decode(json_encode($obj), true); // Convert to array}
    return $array;
}

$xform = parseXmlFile('transformations.xml');
foreach ($xform['product']['data'] as $data)
{
    echo (string)$data['field'] . '<br>';
    echo (string)$data['value'] . '<br>';

    foreach($data['criteria']->attributes() as $att => $val)
    { echo $att . ' = ' . $val . '<br>'; }
    echo $data['criteria']->attributes()->{'field'} . '<br>';

    foreach($data['criteria']['criteria_list'] as $att => $val)
    { echo $att . ' = ' . $val . '<br>'; }

    echo "-----------------------------------<br>";
}

print "<pre>";
print_r($xform);
print "</pre>";
```

I've tried a couple methods as you can see in the code, but neither are working for me.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is when you load the file.
I tried it with `file_get_contents()` See below

```
$xml_content = file_get_contents('path to your XML file');
$xform = simplexml_load_string($xml_content);

foreach ($xform['product']['data'] as $data)
{
    echo (string)$data['field'] . '<br>';
    echo (string)$data['value'] . '<br>';

    foreach($data['criteria']->attributes() as $att => $val)
    { echo $att . ' = ' . $val . '<br>'; }
    echo $data['criteria']->attributes()->{'field'} . '<br>';

    foreach($data['criteria']['criteria_list'] as $att => $val)
    { echo $att . ' = ' . $val . '<br>'; }

    echo "-----------------------------------<br>";
}

print "<pre>";
print_r($xform);
print "</pre>";
```

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot about my xml helper function.  I added it to the code.

Comment: If I use your top two lines of code, and change everything from ['field]' to ->field then it works.  So the issue is after it is converted to an array using the json de/encode.

Answer (score 1):

Your `parseXmlFile` function can be replaced completely with the built-in [`simplexml_load_file()`](http://php.net/simplexml_load_file):

- it loads the contents with `file_get_contents` first; `simplexml_load_file` vs `simplexml_load_string` will do this for you
- it forces the `LIBXML_NO_CDATA` option, which is almost certainly not something you need; to get the text contents of a SimpleXML object - including CDATA - you use `(string)$node`
- it converts the incredibly useful SimpleXML object into an array that will be missing half of the data and much worse to work with

To understand SimpleXML, look at [the examples in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php). Elements are accessed with `->name` and attributes with `['name']`.

So:

```
$xform = simplexml_load_file('transformations.xml');
foreach ($xform->product->data as $data)
{
    echo (string)$data->field . '<br>';
    echo (string)$data->value . '<br>';

    foreach($data->criteria->attributes() as $att => $val)
    { echo $att . ' = ' . $val . '<br>'; }

    echo $data->criteria['field'] . '<br>';

    foreach($data->criteria->criteria_list as $number => $node)
    { echo $number . ' = ' . (string)$node . '<br>'; }

    echo "-----------------------------------<br>";
}
```